# DiscoveryFailedException for the newly created Azure App Registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

Recently we have done new App Registration which is exactly same as the previous App Registrations. And, we landed in the issue to use Microsoft.Office365.Discovery v1.0.22 NuGet service discovery library for Office 365 APIs.

> **Exception of type 'Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryFailedException' was thrown
>   at Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryClient.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---** 
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryClient.d__14.MoveNext()\r\n--- 
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n

**Code**

```
            var result = new Dictionary<String, AuthenticationResult>();

        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("{0}/{1}", "https://login.windows.net", tenantId));

        //authenticate discovery so we can auth all endpoints
        var discoveryAccess = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode, redirectUri, credential, m_sDiscoverySvcResourceId);
        result.Add(m_sDiscoverySvcResourceId, discoveryAccess);

        //discover endpoints
        try
        {
            DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(m_uriDiscoverySvcEndpointUri, () => { return discoveryAccess.AccessToken; });

            var services = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilitiesAsync();
            foreach (var service in services)
            {
                var srvId = service.Value.ServiceResourceId;

                result[srvId] = discoveryAccess;
            }

        }
        catch (DiscoveryFailedException e)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
        return result;
```

**same code runs fine with previously created App Registrations. Appreciate any help**

Comment: Did you make the AAD App multi-tenanted?

Comment: yes it is multi-tenanted AAD app.  We have couple of similar which were previously created. It is exact copy of AAD apps we already have and code works fine.  This issue is only for the one we created recently.

Comment: Did you add the Office 365 API Access through the portal?

Comment: Generally there's some small dissimilarity which causes that - that's why I was asking the clarification questions.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Mavi.  Not sure if I am giving you expected answer. But, what we do is,  the app registration with delegated permissions for Skype for Business, OneNote, Office 365 SharePoint Online, Office 365 Exchange Online, Windows Azure Active Directory..

Comment: @MaviDomates Really appreciate your help. Please could you let me know if you need any more information.